# .net core 2.1 validation state: invalid

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The following simple .NET Core 2.1 MVC code reports "Validation State: Invalid" when I submit to create. Everything works fine without the Owner property; and it works if Owner property is not required.

The Owner is the current user which is in the context of the server side, and it shouldn't be submitted from a client side, so the Create.cshtml doesn't have a Owner input in the form.

The error:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method AnnouncementApp.Controllers.AnnouncementsController.Create (AnnouncementApp) with arguments (AnnouncementApp.Models.Announcement) - Validation state: Invalid
```

The model:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using AnnouncementApp.Models.Attributes;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
//using System.Security.Claims;

namespace AnnouncementApp.Models
{
    public class Announcement
    {   
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Content { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Start Date and Time")]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        [StartEndDate("End Date and Time must be after Start Date and Time")]
        [Display(Name = "End Date and Time")]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [BindNever]
        public IdentityUser Owner { get; set; }
    }   
}
```

The controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,Content,StartDate,EndDate")] Announcement announcement)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(this.User);
            announcement.Owner = user;
            _context.Add(announcement);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(announcement);
    }
```

The Create.cshtml

```
@model AnnouncementApp.Models.Announcement

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<h4>Announcement</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Content" class="control-label"></label>
                <textarea asp-for="Content" class="form-control"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="Content" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StartDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="StartDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="StartDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="EndDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="EndDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="EndDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: Do you need a hidden field for ID?

Comment: No, I don't. I think Required and BindNever just conflict. Required seems taking priority. I want to set it Required because I want the entity framework scaffolding make the CREATE TABLE sql have NOT NULL on the result OwnerId column; but that breaks the model binding validation.

Comment: int should translate to NOT NULL. int? (or nullable data types) translates to NULL. But you might want to consider creating a set of ViewModels separate from you domain model. The domain models can correlate to the database and the ViewModels correlate to the web page.

Comment: @sean is correct.  Why ever include something you never want passed from clientside to be a clientside validation?  Do a ViewModel with only what you need for the view to pass any test and your validation of the inputs.

Comment: @sean is correct. I should've split ViewModel from domain model. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For `Announcement`, it will apply `[Required]` for both client validation and database table.

As the comments indicates, you could consider split `Announcement` to Db Model and ViewModel, you could define a new `AnnouncementViewModel` for client validation.

For another option, you could try configure the `[Required]` in the fluent api instead of attribute.

Here are the detail steps.

1. Change `Announcement`

   ```
   public class Announcement
   {
   public int ID { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public string Content { get; set; }
   [Display(Name = "Start Date and Time")]
   public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
   public string OwnerId { get; set; }
   //[Required]
   [BindNever]
   [ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
   public IdentityUser Owner { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Fluent api in `ApplicationDbContext`

   ```
       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
   {
       base.OnModelCreating(builder);

       builder.Entity<Announcement>()
              .Property(a => a.OwnerId)
              .IsRequired();           
   }
   ```
3. Controller

   ```
       [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,Content,StartDate")] Announcement announcement)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
           announcement.Owner = user;
           _context.Add(announcement);
           await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
           return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
       }
       return View(announcement);
   }
   ```

Comment: Fluent API probably is overkill. ViewModel is a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100 % sure, what you define as the issue, but if you want to supress the "Model Invalid" error, since you are always setting the Owner property through the HttpContext, you can use the following before validating the model:

```
ModelState["Owner"].ValidationState = ModelValidationState.Valid
```

I think your issue is that you tell the router to never bind "Owner", but you still tells it is required, and therefore the ModelState would potentially invalidate it.

As long as the "Required" annotation is used, I do not think the ModelState will validate without it being set correctly.

Example:

```
ModelState["Owner"].ValidationState = ModelValidationState.Valid
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(this.User);
            announcement.Owner = user;
            _context.Add(announcement);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(announcement);
```

Comment: It probably isn't good practice to force the state valid. I'll just split ViewModel from Domain Model